# Plot CVI and SVI in EVA graphical report

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2007

I am using Project 2007 to perform the calculation related to the EVA methodology. Everything works as expected, and when I generate the earned value over time graphical report I have the correct values of BCWP, BCWS and ACWP.

However, I would like to get the VALUE of CVI and SVI in the same pivot graph, but I am not able to find a way to add these two values, which actually are just the rations of the other ones.

Is there a way to plot SVI and CVI similarly to BCWP, BCWS and ACWP?

Answer (score 1):

I no longer have access to a 2007 version, so I can't check if this works, but have you tried editing the template of your visual report? Each template has a restricted set of fields available, but this can be extended manually.

- On the Report menu, click Visual Reports.
- On the All tab, click the report that you want to edit.
- If you know which category contains the report, you can click that
  category's tab to view a shorter list of reports.
- Click Edit Template.
- On the Visual Reports - Field Picker dialog box, click the fields
  that you want to add or remove from the report, and then click Add,
  Remove, or Remove All to move fields between the Available Fields and
  Selected Fields boxes, or between the Available Custom Fields and
  Selected Custom Fields boxes.
- Fields in the Selected Fields and Selected Custom Fields boxes are
  included in the report.
- Click Edit Template to create the report with the modified list of
  fields.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-visual-report-6e2d08a8-3f84-4af5-a457-d5f83403adbc#bm3

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. With this solution I can only plot CV and SV in absolute values, but not the indexes CVI and SVI. Do new versions of Microsoft project support this?

Comment: Yes, I have Project 2016 and I was able to add the fields.